# Elementary Set Theory, Proof involving empty sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

$$ \emptyset , \{\emptyset\} $$ **prove that these are 2 distinct sets  :**

---

I want to check my proof writing and whether I am thinking correctly or not

***My proof :-***  Firstly, assume $$ \emptyset = \{\emptyset\}$$
$$\therefore \forall x  (x \in \emptyset \iff x \in \{ \emptyset \})$$
By definition of the empty set:
$$\emptyset =: \{x \notin \emptyset\}$$
By definition of the singleton set:
$$ x \in \{ \emptyset \} \iff x=\emptyset$$
Therefore not every element in $ \{ \emptyset \} $ is in $\emptyset$ , then by contradiction:  $$ \emptyset \neq \{\emptyset\}$$

---

Comment: "*prove that these are 2 distinct sets*"... I don't understand why this needs proof... the set on the left has zero elements while the set on the right has one element.  As for what you've written, I don't agree with your "definition of the empty set"... the way I read that is the set of all $x$ who are not elements of the empty set which one might interpret as being a universal set rather than an empty set.

Comment: As for writing why they are different?  $\{\emptyset\}$ has an element, that element namely being $\emptyset$.  $\emptyset$ on the other hand has no elements... $\{\emptyset\}$ having an element that $\emptyset$ doesn't have shows they are different.

Comment: Yea I know its obvious but I took it straight out of a text and the author had a similar proof to mine